# The force of a spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, spring, continuum-mechanics

I am new in continuum mechanics and I want to prove the formula which gives the force given by a spring :

$$F_{max}= \frac{Ed^4(L-nd)}{16(1+\nu)(D-d)^3 n}$$

where :

$E$ – Young's modulus

$d$ – spring wire diameter

$L$ – free length of spring

$n$ – number of active windings

$\nu$ – Poisson ratio

$D$ – spring outer diameter

See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_(device)

I think this is not easy to prove, do you have a reference in the internet or scientifical article ?

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you ! At least it shows that the problem is not really easy, and my case is the helical cylindrical compression spring with round wires and bars to be precise.

Comment: Just a comment. One does not 'prove' physical models. Physicists, engineers use analysis and principles to develop models and verify the models using experimental data. The models are almost never exact. We leave proof strictly to the mathematical world.

Comment: I know that and I am just looking for a proof that rest on continuum mechanics which have its own principles of course